# css border and backgroundcolor not rendered on webkit browser

Tags: css, webkit

This might be quite a dumb question, but clearly I haven't been able to figure it out alone.

If you go to [this](http://cluster006.ovh.net/~printroo/category/shop/) page with a non-webkit browser you will notice how the three articles at the bottom have a black border and a white background, but if you do the same with chrome or safari, those css proprieties disappears.

The css for that element looks like this:

```
body.category-shop article{
-moz-box-flex:1;    
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-o-box-flex:1;      

border:solid #000;
background-color:#FFF;
height:250px;
width:100%;
margin:0 10px;
padding:5px;}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you a lot, and sorry for the super-personal question.

Comment: You did not define the WIDTH of the border.

Comment: Hint: it cannot be a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the flexbox model, you don't need floats.

The background and border should display once you remove `float: left` from `body.archive article`.